# Sending push notifications to multiple devices FCM API V1

Tags: curl, post, firebase-cloud-messaging

Could you please tell me if it is possible to send cloud message with curl to multiple devices in Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1) as it was in Cloud Messaging API (Legacy)?

```
{
   "message":{
      "token":"",
      "notification":{
        "body":"This is an FCM notification message!",
        "title":"FCM Message"
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to register topic insite app, like

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("theme_name");
```

Then:

```
{
  "to": "/topics/theme_name",
  "notification": {
    "title": "title",
    "body": "Body"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint, then push notifications will come to which users?

Comment: Users which are subscribed to theme_name

Comment: How do users sign up for this thread?

Comment: Can I add a token to a topic using an http request (curl)?

Comment: Users need to subscribe on topic by theyself. And they are do it on way like i explaine in first part of comment (topic can be register on MainActivity )